# .NET Compact Framework Transparent UserControl

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-ce, transparent

I am programming a mobile application. I need a `UserControl` (emulating the `TabContol` navigation - the customer wants the tabs at the top) with a transparent background. The control contains three buttons each with an `OnClick` handler.

In Googling, I've found a number of solutions for WinForms. But they seemed incompatible with Win Mobile. I used the [Christian Helle blog](http://christian-helle.blogspot.com/2008/01/transparent-controls-in-netcf.html) for a transparent label used in the app, but cannot wrap my mind around modifying it for `UserControl`s.

TIA, Gus

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's a complex task - way more complex than it should be, but it is what it is.  While I never actually finished [Project Resistance](http://resistance.codeplex.com/), it *does* have code for transparent user controls

The resistor body itself is a UserControl, the background shows through the surrounding area and it even dynamically draws the color bands so that the resistor body shows through the band transparent areas.

Comment: looked over the Project Resistance. Unfortunately, it does not compile ('ProjectResistance.EventNames' does not contain a definition for 'DPadEvent'). Did find the GraphicsTools and hope to find how to apply those paradigms. Still not quite the answer I'd have expected though. Thanks for your input. - Gus

Comment: I'll take a look at the compilation issue - it should at least work - we stopped at a point where the app at least was somewhat functional and that's what should be up there.  I apologize that I couldn't provide an answer, but the solution is actually a bit too complex to be able to post as an answer here on SO as it involves not just the Control, but custom drawing even in the Control's Parent, plus getting past a bug or two in the CF itself.

Comment: May I, at the risk of requesting too much, ask that you write a Code Project article that explains the solution using a simple example (say, of a CF Form with a UserControl, containing three buttons, that allows the Form's background to show through the UserControl. Of course, the buttons would be opaque). I think that the important issue is simply that there appear to be a number of ways to get the desired result in Win Forms but not so using the CF.

Comment: I'd love to do that, but to be completely honest I simply don't have the time - at least not in the next few weeks.  I'll get the stuff in Codeplex building, but that's as far as I can go at this point.  Project Resistance is only one form with 2 UserControls, so it's really not bad.  Just look at the drawing of the Controls and the Parent Form.